# Delete topic in Kafka 0.8.1.1

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to delete the topic `test` in Apache Kafka 0.8.1.1.

As expressed in the [documentation here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_modify_topic), I have executed:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic test
```

However, this results in the following message:

```
Command must include exactly one action: --list, --describe, --create or --alter
```

How can I delete this topic?

Comment: Step by step procedure is explained in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537950/how-to-delete-a-topic-in-apache-kafka

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Deleting topic isn't always working in 0.8.1.1

Deletion should be working in the next release, 0.8.2

```
kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic your_topic_name

  Topic your_topic_name is marked for deletion.
  Note: This will have no impact if delete.topic.enable is not set to true.
```

You may also pass in a bootstrap server instead of zookeeper:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --delete --topic your_topic_name
```

[Is it possible to delete a topic?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Isitpossibletodeleteatopic?)

[Jira KAFKA-1397](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1397)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know how to clear the entire Kafka and Zookeeper states as indicated?

Comment: @EmPack IIRC, the easiest way to do that (if you don't care about up time) is to shutdown all your brokers, delete your logs for that topic and changing you ZK namespace.

Answer (score 96):

It seems that the deletion command was not officially documented in Kafka 0.8.1.x because of a known bug (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1397).

Nevertheless, the command was still shipped in the code and can be executed as:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.DeleteTopicCommand --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

In the meantime, the bug got fixed and the deletion command is now officially available from Kafka 0.8.2.0 as:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

Comment: From what I read, it might work 0.8.1.1, but it might not... The fix is also in the trunk since a while, so if you took the sources directly from the trunk, it should work

Comment: I've just tried on 0.8.1.1, it reports "deletion succeeded" but it didn't work. Topic is still there, I can attach a consumer and it will report all previous items as pending.

Comment: Deleting topics in Kafka 0.8.1.1 does not work.  The recently released version 0.8.2.0  should finally have proper deletion support.  See http://blog.confluent.io/2014/12/02/whats-coming-in-apache-kafka-0-8-2/.

Comment: BTW, the property for delete.topic.enable=true can be located in the server.properties file. It is commented out by default.

Answer (score 40):

Add below line in ${kafka_home}/config/server.properties

```
delete.topic.enable=true
```

Restart the kafka server with new config:

```
${kafka_home}/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties
```

Delete the topics you wish to:

```
${kafka_home}/bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete  --zookeeper localhost:2181  --topic daemon12
```

Comment: This was not working until I read your comment about restarting the server. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 10):

Andrea is correct. we can do it using command line.

And we still can program it, by

```
ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient("localhost:2181", 10000);
zkClient.deleteRecursive(ZkUtils.getTopicPath("test2"));
```

Actually I do not recommend you delete topic on Kafka 0.8.1.1. I can delete this topic by this method, but if you check log for zookeeper, deletion mess it up.

Comment: Should it also include zkClient.deleteRecursive(ZkUtils.getTopicConfigPath("test2")); and

Comment: @Sumit, and what? I did not use that "getTopicConfigPath". Actually I do not recommend you delete topic on Kafka 0.8.1.1. I can delete this topic by this method, but if you check log for zookeeper, deletion mess it up.

Comment: but this is how kafka also does it (the way you suggested): https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/DeleteTopicCommand.scala

Comment: @Sumit. yes, I found the code from there. I am not sure about that "messy up" thing. Because once I delete a topic on my company server, the deletion generate lots of junk to zookeeper log. But I can not reproduce it in my local. So I do not recommend that..

Answer (score 5):

Steps to Delete 1 or more Topics in Kafka

#To delete topics in kafka the delete option needs to be enabled in Kafka server.
1. Go to {kafka_home}/config/server.properties
2. Uncomment delete.topic.enable=true

#Delete one Topic in Kafka enter the following command

```
kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <your_topic_name>
```

#To Delete more than one topic from kafka
(good for testing purposes, where i created multiple topics & had to delete them for different scenarios)

1. Stop the Kafka Server and Zookeeper
2. go to server folder where the logs are stored (defined in their config files) and delete the kafkalogs and zookeeper folder manually
3. Restart the zookeeper and kafka server and try to list topics,

bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

if no topics are listed then the all topics have been deleted successfully.If topics are listed, then the delete was not successful. Try the above steps again or restart your computer.

Comment: Note that for the latest Kafka version at the moment (1.0.0) that option doesn't appears in the ``server.properties`` file. You have to add that line manually.

Comment: @DavidCorral topic deletion is enabled by default in 1.0.0

Answer (score 4):

You can delete a specific kafka topic (example: `test`) from zookeeper shell command (`zookeeper-shell.sh`).  Use the below command to delete the topic

```
rmr {path of the topic}
```

example:

```
rmr /brokers/topics/test
```

Comment: set delete.topic.enable=true, then delete from kafka then also delete from zookeeper...

Comment: This does **not** delete topic data on the actual broker

Answer (score 3):

**This steps will delete all topics and data**

- Stop Kafka-server and Zookeeper-server
- Remove the data directories of both services, by default on windows they are
  C:/tmp/kafka-logs and C:/tmp/zookeeper.
- then start Zookeeper-server and Kafka-server

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in doc [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_modify_topic)

> Topic deletion option is disabled by default. To enable it set the server config
>   delete.topic.enable=true
>   Kafka does not currently support reducing the number of partitions for a topic or changing the replication factor.

Make sure delete.topic.enable=true

Comment: I believe that option is only available in 8.2

Answer (score 2):

The command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

unfortunately only marks topic for deletion.

**Deletion** does not happen.

That makes troubles, while testing any scripts, which prepares Kafka configuration.

Connected threads:

- [Purge Kafka Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284399/purge-kafka-queue)
- [Is there a way to delete all the data from a topic or delete the topic before every run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730905/is-there-a-way-to-delete-all-the-data-from-a-topic-or-delete-the-topic-before-ev)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to above answers one has to delete the meta data associated with that topic in zookeeper consumer offset path.

`bin/zookeeper-shell.sh zookeeperhost:port`

`rmr /consumers/<sample-consumer-1>/offsets/<deleted-topic>`

Otherwise the lag will be negative in kafka-monitoring tools based on zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

First, you run this command to delete your topic:

```sh
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic <topic_name>
```

List active topics to check delete completely:

```sh
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`kafka-topics --delete --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic  user-commands`

I am using Confluent CLI and run this on the directory I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topic-name>
```

Comment: This **marks** a topic for deletion, not blocks and waits for deletion

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues deleting the topics, try to delete the topic using:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic your_topic_name
```

command. Then in order to verify the deletion process, go to the kafka logs directory which normally is placed under `/tmp/kafka-logs/`, then delete the `your_topic_name` file via `rm -rf your_topic_name` command.

Remember to monitor the whole process via a kafka management tool like `Kafka Tool`.

The mentioned process above will remove the topics without kafka server restart.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Make sure you are connected to zookeeper and Kafka running

Step 2: To delele the Kafka topic run kafka-topics script, add the port and --topic with name of your topic and --delete it just delete the topic with success.

```
# Delete the kafka topic
# it will delete the kafka topic
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic name_of_topic --delete
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a solution without touching those `bin/kafka-*.sh`: If you have installed `kafdrop`, then simply do:

```
url -XPOST http://your-kafdrop-domain/topic/THE-TOPIC-YOU-WANT-TO-DELETE/delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent Kafka versions are about to remove the Zookeeper dependency. Therefore, you should instead reference the brokers (through `--boostrap-server`):

```
kafka-topics \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 \
    --delete \
    --topic topic_for_deletion
```

Answer (score 0):

for confluent cloud use -

```
$ confluent kafka topic delete my_topic
```