# How can I delete a topic in Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I need to delete a topic in Kafka 0.8.2.2.3. I have used the below command for deleting the topic:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic DummyTopic
```

The command executed successfully, but when I run a command to list the topics, I could see that the topic is still there and it shows **marked for deletion**.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
DummyTopic - marked for deletion
```

And when I create the topic DummyTopic, it outputs the exception. The topic already exists, and below is the stack trace:

```
Error while executing topic command Topic "DummyTopic" already exists.
kafka.common.TopicExistsException: Topic "DummyTopic" already exists.
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createOrUpdateTopicPartitionAssignmentPathInZK(AdminUtils.scala:248)
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:233)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:92)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:54)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

How can I delete this topic?

Comment: Apache Kafka never deletes a topic marked for deletion if that topic has producers still producing to it, or consumers still consuming from it, or messages left hanging out in the queue.  One way to try to try to force it is to restart Kafka.  Or if that doesn't work, go in under the hood and Delete the directory that is your topic name under /var/local/kafka/data and then restart Kafka then re-issue the delete command.  I wish Apache Kafka had a "nuke the bleeping topic" option so the developer can issue the command: "Really, totes for real this time nuke the bleeping topic no sass please".

Comment: bin/kafka-topics.sh –delete –zookeeper localhost:2181 –topic <topic-name>

Comment: Option zookeeper is deprecated, use --bootstrap-server instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429129/5456789

Comment: This worked for me (within docker): bin/kafka-topics --delete --topic DummyTopic   --bootstrap-server localhost:29092

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Deletion of a topic has been supported since 0.8.2.x version. You have to enable topic deletion (setting `delete.topic.enable` to true) on all brokers first.

Note: Ever since 1.0.x, the functionality being stable, `delete.topic.enable` is by default `true`.

Follow this step by step process for manual deletion of topics

1. Stop *Kafka* server
2. Delete the topic directory, on each *broker* (as defined in the `logs.dirs` and `log.dir` properties) with `rm -rf` command
3. Connect to *Zookeeper* instance: `zookeeper-shell.sh host:port`
4. From within the *Zookeeper* instance:

   1. List the topics using: `ls /brokers/topics`
   2. Remove the topic folder from *ZooKeeper* using: `rmr /brokers/topics/yourtopic`
   3. Exit the Zookeeper instance (Ctrl+C)
5. Restart *Kafka* server
6. Confirm if it was deleted or not by using this command
   `kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper host:port`

Comment: ok...thanks...I will try restarting the kafka cluster..:)

Comment: Link is broken!

Comment: Where is the "/brokers/topics" directory? cant seem to find that folder

Comment: Use `zookeeper-shell.sh` to get to zookeeper and `ls /brokers/topics`

Comment: If I check the docs on bin/kafka-topics.sh I see a --delete option. But using it does not work. Is it still in beta?

Comment: NOTE: If u use --delete from kafka-topics.sh ---> make sure there is no CONSUMER running ---> and you set 'delete.topic.enable:true' in server.properties file on all kafka brokers.

Comment: `kafka.admin.TopicCommand` shows how to do this programmatically.

Comment: how to delete all topics not just one?

Comment: i cant believe its so difficult to delete a topic

Comment: @ErikK Is there a better way?

Comment: `rmr` command is deprecated. you can use `deleteall` instead of `rmr`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this rm -rf approach for prod clusters. The proper way is to enable delete topic in server.properties.
Use --delete
Wait for the offsets to expire naturally on these topics. 
The zookeeper shell uninstall works too but causes controller node to change.

Comment: windows users can run zookeeper-shell.bat <zk address>, for example: zookeeper-shell.bat localhost:2821. btw, there is deleteall command

Comment: I visit this answer every couple of weeks. Sometimes multiple times in a week.

Comment: Don't delete the folders while kafka is still running! (an easy concept to grasp which I am learning currently the hard way how to deal with)

Comment: Hmm.. now we just need to use the command mentioned in the query `bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic DummyTopic` and voila it's done.

Comment: **Note** one issue which caught me out was that our kafka cluster is configured to auto create topics = true. I had to change the value of `auto.create.topics.enable` to `false` in `conf/server.properties` without this the topic may be automatically created when data arrives and with the default partition/replicas setup.