# Clearing Kafka Topics without setting retention Days

Tags: apache-kafka

I understand that there are other options to emptying Kafka topics besides tearing down the topic or setting the retention days to seconds.

Does anyone know what those options are?  If so, can you post some examples?

Comment: IMHO the simplest option would be to [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537950/how-to-delete-a-topic-in-apache-kafka) and recreate the topic

Comment: What you listed are the only options... What else were you expecting?

Comment: Thanks.  That does help.  I thought there was another way of doing it but I guess I was wrong.