# zookeeper is not a recognized option when executing kafka-console-consumer.sh

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm learning how to use Kafka on this website [link](https://data-artisans.com/blog/kafka-flink-a-practical-how-to)(except I'm using port 2182 in zookeeper), but it shows:

> zookeeper is not a recognized option

after executing:

> sudo ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test --zookeeper
> localhost:2182

How to fix it?

Env:

```
kafka_2.11-2.1.0
zookeeper-3.4.10
```

Comment: You don't need sudo to run these commands

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I find the answer on the [QUICKSTART](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart):

> Option `zookeeper` is deprecated, use `--bootstrap-server` instead.

Now it works:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Comment: latest kafka using bootstrap-server

Comment: To create topic use `kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

Comment: Definitely worked! replaced --zookeeper with --bootstrap-server (btw, I'm using kafka 2.13-3.5.0)

Answer (score 20):

For windows

**To start zookeeper**

```
C:\kafka-2.12>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

**To start Kafka Broker**

```
C:\kafka-2.12>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

**To Create topic**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

**Start Producer**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

**To create consumer**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

**Topic creation With multi partition with replication factor 1**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic first_topic --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

**To get the list of topic created in system**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
```

**To get the description of topic created in system**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

**To delete topic test created in system**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-run-class.bat kafka.admin.TopicCommand --delete --topic test --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

**To read message from beginning of topic test created in system(version>2.0)**

```
C:\kafka-2.12\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginn
```

Answer (score 9):

For windows users use

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Comment: remove 'bin' and execute the command from 'bin/windows' folder.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

- From version 2.1.* the previous answers may not work, always check the official [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) , this answer provided with version `3.1.0` .

For Linux kernel base systems

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic yourTopicname --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

For Windows systems

```
./kafka-topics.bat --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

No need to pass `--from-beginning` when there is no initial offset and overload the creation command with desired [configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs)