# Confusion about delete Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka 0.8.0, it's Cloudera version.
When I deleted the topic such as: `kafka-topics --zookeeper 10.0.0.11:2181/ --delete --topic test`
it response:

```
Topic test is already marked for deletion.
```

But afterwards I recreated it, it throw exception as following:

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper 10.0.0.11:2181 --partitions 90 --replication-factor 2 --topic test

Error while executing topic command Topic "test" already exists.
kafka.common.TopicExistsException: Topic "test" already exists.
```

Any ideas please? How should I delete the topic and it's data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete topic in Kafka 0.8.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287900/delete-topic-in-kafka-0-8-1-1)

Answer (score 7):

My Kakfa version is kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2, below link works for me (from [Delete topic in Kafka 0.8.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287900/delete-topic-in-kafka-0-8-1-1))

Add below line in `${kafka_home}/config/server.properties`

```
delete.topic.enable=true
```

Restart the kafka server with new config:

```
${kafka_home}/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties
```

Delete the topics you wish to:

```
${kafka_home}/bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic daemon12
```

More information from [Kafka FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Isitpossibletodeleteatopic?):

> Deleting a topic is supported since 0.8.2.x. You will need to enable
>   topic deletion (setting delete.topic.enable to true) on all brokers
>   first.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure that, In kafka's config.poperties file 'delete.topic.enable' property should be true.
2. use below command

   bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test

Even if topic is not deleted then follow next steps.

3. open terminal zookeeper client mode:

   A. stop zookeeper

   B. rmr /broker/topics

   C. check given topic using below command

   /bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper maxiq:2181 --list

Answer (score 2):

If `delete.topic.enable` is set to false by default, the topics are not deleted on execution of `--delete` command (as displayed in the command response).

```
Topic test is marked for deletion.
Note: This will have no impact if delete.topic.enable is not set to true.
```

In order to overcome this, use steps mentioned by @Shawn

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy to make `delete.topic.enable=true` is not modify the `server.property` file.

Because, if kafka restart from ambari, it will overwrite this file, `delete.topic.enable =false` again.

Only at ambari, click on `kafak/config/advance kafka broker/delete.topic.enable =true`, it will work.

I just found that out as now.

Answer (score 1):

**Delete topic in kafka**
step 1 -->>  cd /usr/lib/zookeeper/bin

step 2 -->> zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181

step 3 -->>rmr /brokers/topics/topic_name