# How to delete kafka topic from cluster version : 0.10.2.1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am not able to delete kafka topic, Its marked for deletion but never gets deleted. Iam running kafka cluster with zookeeper cluster.

version of kafka : 0.10.2.1

Can anyone help me , with the list of steps that one needs to follow in order to delete a topic in **kafka cluster**.

Went through various queries in stackoverflow but could not find a valid workable answer.

Comment: You need to enable deletion on all the brokers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete a topic in apache kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537950/how-to-delete-a-topic-in-apache-kafka)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete topic in Kafka 0.8.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287900/delete-topic-in-kafka-0-8-1-1)

Answer (score 1):

You should have enabled its property at config before starting kafka server; it is disabled at default. To enable deletion property first stop kafka server and then open the *server.properties* in config file 
  and then uncomment `#delete.topic.enable=true` or add
    `delete.topic.enable=true`
      at the end of the file.

Now you can start kafka server and then you can delete any topic you want via:
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic YOUR_TOPIC_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Kafka Tool**

[Download link here](http://www.kafkatool.com/)

Then connect to your `kafka server` .

After that you could see the available topics in that server. From there you can select and delete the topics .

[image]