# Steps to delete data inside the Kafka Topic on Windows?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working on Spring Batch and Apache Kafka Integration. Before posting the question I went over web : [Is there a way to delete all the data from a topic or delete the topic before every run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730905/is-there-a-way-to-delete-all-the-data-from-a-topic-or-delete-the-topic-before-ev) to find out better solution, but did not find out.

I am using Kafka version 2.11.

I want to delete all data under the topic without stopping either Zookeeper or Kafka. How can we do that ?

Below commands causes lot of issues in windows

```
C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic customers
Topic customers is marked for deletion.
Note: This will have no impact if delete.topic.enable is not set to true.

C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic test

C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic customers --from-beginning
[2020-04-21 10:25:02,812] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-65075] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-21 10:25:04,886] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-65075] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-21 10:25:06,996] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-65075] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-21 10:25:09,267] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-65075] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-21 10:25:11,744] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-65075] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
Processed a total of 0 messages
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C
C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\bin\windows>
```

Comment: Have you considered changing the `retention.ms` to 1 and then back to normal as suggested in the posted link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using Kafka version 2.11.

There is no Kafka 2.11. Your command prompt says `kafka_2.11-2.3.1`: hence, you are using Kafka 2.3.1. The 2.11 part is the Scala version that was used during compilation.

> Note: This will have no impact if delete.topic.enable is not set to true.

Did you check your broker configs if `delete.topic.enable` is set to `true`? If yes, you should be able to delete a topic without stopping ZK or the brokers. Note though, that deleting topics is *async*, i.e., when you command returns the topic is not deleted yet and it will take some time until the command is executed.