# does per topic config "kafka-topic.sh --alter" changes made during runtime persist after a reboot?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I use the top answer in this question 
[Purge Kafka Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284399/purge-kafka-queue)
and alter the log.retention.ms, will this change persist after my host gets an unexpected restart?

Answer (score 1):

Any change made using `kafka-topics.sh --alter` is persisted after restart.