# kafka retention policy didn't work as expected

Tags: apache-kafka

I wanted a certain kafka topic to only keep 1 day of data. But it didn't seem to delete any data at all if we keep sending data to the topic(active). I tried topic side parameter (retention.ms) and server side:

```
    log.retention.hours=1 or log.retention.ms= 86400000 
    cleanup.policy=delete
```

But it didn't seem to work for alive topics, if we keep sending data to it. Only when we stop sending data to the topic, it will follow the retention policy.

So, what's the right config for a active topic, to retain data only for some time?

Comment: which version of kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log retention is based on the creation date of the log file. Try setting your `log.roll.hours` < 24 (since [by default](https://kafka.apache.org/08/documentation.html) it is 24 * 7).

### For 0.8

If you only want to control log file creation per topic, set `log.roll.hours.per.topic` in the topic config.

### for 1.0

Logs are segmented and the per topic config for log segments is:

[`segment.ms`](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) Note: this is in millseconds, and overrides the server-wide setting of `log.roll.ms`.

See also: [Purge Kafka Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089883/2718295)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. log.roll.hours helps from the server side. But if I set "log.roll.hours.per.topic", would it apply to all topics? Is there a way to define individual topic to have different roll.hour?

Comment: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs for 0.11 the per topic config is `segment.ms` (which overrides to the `log.roll.ms` serverwide)

Answer (score 5):

Kafka deletes only the passive log segments. You have to tune either `log.segment.bytes` or `log.roll.ms` to roll the active log segment into passive one. Refer the [Broker configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) for more information.

Comment: How to close log faster only for specific topics?