# Kafka doesn't delete old messages in topics

Tags: apache-kafka

In kafka I have set retention policy to 3 days in `server.properties`

```
############################# Log Retention Policy #############################
...
log.retention.hours=72
...
```

Topics has `retention.ms` set to `172800000` (48h).

However, there are still old data in the folder /tmp/kafka-logs and none are being deleted. *I waited few hours after changing those properties.*

Is there something that needs to be set? All topics are being produced to and consumed from currently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Edit: it seems the `cleanup.policy` should default to `delete` according to kafka documentation.*

`retention.ms` or `retention.bytes` specify the way the data are deleted.

---

The key was to set `log.cleanup.policy` to `compact` or `delete`. I had not set this.

Running: `kafka-topics --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic topic1 --describe` shows properties set on topic, eg. `Configs:retention.ms=172800000,cleanup.policy=compact`

The `cleanup.policy` has to be set.  Also I manually set `retention.ms` / `retention.bytes` to control cleanup trigger.

Comment: Note also that the sizes of the log segments will also affect this behavior.

Answer (score 8):

`Compact` policy will only **compact** values from a key. That is, it will eventually trigger compaction processes that will leave only one (the final) value for a key. But not delete the last value, ever.

In order to trigger **deletion** by time, you need to set `delete` policy. In that case, the deletion process will delete data older than the given one.

However you can set up policy as `compact,delete` to take advantage both processes over the same topic (not available in earlier versions).

However, these processes are not second-exact: **they will be triggered eventually** following some conditions, like:

```
# The interval at which log segments are checked to see 
# if they can be deleted according to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
```

(check more conditions on [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) and then will guarantee that data older than the threshold will be deleted.

In addition, there are different settings for different **time granularity**, and they have priorities (if one is set, it will ignore the next). Make sure there is no unexpected overriding. Please check the comprehensive documentation for details.

Comment: `log.retention.check.interval.ms` gives "Unknown topic config name: log.retention.check.interval.ms"

Comment: This is broker config. Maybe you're setting it up somewhere else? You can find details here: 
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: Ok my bad, I was searching in Topic Configuration

Answer (score 2):

As described in [kafka retention policy didn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448576/kafka-retention-policy-didnt-work-as-expected) :

Log retention is based on the creation date of the log file. Try setting your `log.roll.hours` < 24 (since [by default][1] it is 24 * 7).

Comment: I set this property but has not effect. I have now logs older than 7*24 so I suppose this is not it. I guess kafka doesn't trigger the purge at all.

Comment: I noticed the topic `consumer offsets` was being deleted but my topics were not. Did the compare and it was caused by not setting cleanup policy, see my answer. But thanks anyway!