# How to purge or delete a topic in kafka 2.1.0 version

Tags: apache-kafka

Would like to share different ways to purge or delete a kafka topic in 2.1.0 version. I've found similar question here [Purge Kafka Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284399/purge-kafka-topic) however, the accepted answer has been deprecated and it works on Kafka version 0.8 and below hence, creating this question with answer.

This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purge Kafka Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284399/purge-kafka-topic)

Comment: Just because nothing was accepted doesn't mean you need to duplicate the answers there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kafka by default keeps the messages for 168 hrs which is 7 days. If you wanted to force kafka to purge the topic, you can do this by multiple ways. Let’s see each in detail.

**1. Using kafka-configs.sh command**

Temporarily change the retention policy to 1 sec.

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --add-config retention.ms=1000 --entity-name text_topic
```

You can check the current value of retention policy by running below command.

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --describe --entity-name text_topic
Configs for topic 'text_topic' are retention.ms=1000
```

Wait for 1 sec and remove the retention policy config which will set it back to default.

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --delete-config retention.ms --entity-name text_topic
```

**2. Delete topic and re-create**

Before we delete an existing topic, first get the partition and replica of the current topic as you would need these to re-create the topic. You can get this information by running describe of the topic

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic text_topic

Topic:text_topic        PartitionCount:3        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: text_topic       Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

Delete the topic.

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic text_topic
```

Re-create the topic with replication and partition details.

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic text_topic
```

**3. Manually delete the data from kafka logs.**

1. Stop zookeeper and kafka from all nodes.
2. Clean kafka logs from all nodes. kafka stores its log files at
   /tmp/kafka-logs/MyTopic-0 where /tmp/kafka-logs is specified by the
   log.dirattribute
3. Restart zookeeper and kafka.

Hope this helps !!