# Kafka - delete a topic completely

Tags: apache-kafka

Seems difficult to achieve. When I delete a topic and then recreate it with the same name, I notice the previous partitions are already present, which suggests the deletion has not been thorough. I would like to make the topic disappear completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kafka-topics --delete` operation is asynchronous.

The only way to guarantee a topic is completely deleted would be to manually run `rm -rf` on each broker in the cluster where a replica exists, then also use `zookeeper-shell` to remove the topic ZNode entry

Comment: I'm trying to use zookeeper-shell but I get "JLine support is disabled" :(

Comment: Hmm. Never seen that before. Still, it's not really recommended to delete and topic then recreate. Instead, you can [purge it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984801/2308683) through retention settings. Or, just create a brand new topic with `-v2` suffix, for example