# Remove files in kafka without

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to get space on one of my kafka server. And i would want to know if i can remove the oldest files

- *.index
- *.log
- *.snapshot

[image]

without issues on my Kafka?

I've read different documentations afterwards i m not sure it's why i come to you.
[kafka storag and log](https://www.conduktor.io/blog/understanding-kafkas-internal-storage-and-log-retention/)

i didn't tried anything for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the files and restart the broker, then those files may come back due to topic replication.

It is better to [alter/lower the topic retention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284399/is-there-a-way-to-purge-the-topic-in-kafka) so that Kafka removes those files on its own.